# django ajax filter

Tags: ajax, django

Есть моделька

```
class WinF(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
```

вьюшка

```
def home(request):
    arctic = WinF.objects.all()
    cont = {'arctic': arctic }
    return render(request, 'Mysitez/home.html', cont)
```

и блок вывода

```
{% for arctics in arctic %}
      <option value="{{ arctics.user }}">{{ arctics.user }}</option>
{% endfor %}

{% for arctics in arctic %}
      <h4>{{ arctics.title }}</h4>
      <pre>{{ arctics.get_shor_text }}</pre>
{% endfor %}
```

хочется прикрутить ajax фильтр по useram с выводом на страницу тайтлов и техтов выбранного юзера
,знания js очень слабые, мне хотяб какойнить пример чтоб прикрутить и понять как оно работает